# What do these two 'x' mean in this Python code: self.x = x?

Tags: python, self

I'm confused in bellowing code:

```python
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

I do not understand what those two `x` in code `self.x = x` mean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 'self' explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`self.x` is an attribute of the Point class. So if p is an instance of the Point class, then `p.x` is the `self.x` you see above (self being a reference to the class you are defining). The second `x` is the parameter passed at init time `def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):`. Note that it defaults to zero in case you don't pass anything.

Comment: >`self.x` is an attribute of the Point class< better: > `self.x` is an attribute of a Point class instance<

Answer (score 7):

The first `x` is an attribute of `self`, while the second comes into the method as its second argument.

You could write it as:

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, new_x=0, new_y=0):
        self.x = new_x
        self.y = new_y
```

and see which belongs to which one.

Answer (score 2):

First read this question and answer: [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained). To your question, the first `self.x` is an attribute of `self` and the second `x` is an argument you are getting in your constructor for `Point`

Comment: I did a search before I ask, and I have seen that question and answer, I found I still can not solve my confuse. that's why I ask. Actually some of explains in that answers is difficult to understand for me. But that answers are good for me. thanks.

Comment: I didn't imply you didn't make any research, I just pointed out a good starting point for you to read, so that my answer would make sense without having to explain what `self` is... cheers.

Comment: My mistake, I should clarify that I have checkout those questions.

Answer (score -2):

```
class Employee:
   def __init__(self, name, salary):
       self.name = name
       self.salary = salary    # self ? ? ?

   def displayEmployee(self):
       salary  =  -69 
       print self.name, self.salary,salary    # self ? ? ?
```

run:

```
emp1 = Employee("nick", 2000)

emp1.displayEmployee()      # self ! ! !
```

output:

nick 2000 -69

'self' explained! :  self.salary  =  2000   ,   salary  =  -69

Comment: Mind adding even a little bit of explanation as to how this applies?

Comment: Explain everything. It is unclear how it applies to the question, especially for a user who doesn't understand the topic well

Comment: This 'self' topic has been 'explained' by many others , so try some other explanation if you don't like mine.